# Использование ORDER BY и GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by, order, order-by

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с запросом.
Мне нужно посчитать стоимость всех экземпляров каждого автора без учета книг «Идиот» и «Белая гвардия». В результат включить только тех авторов, у которых суммарная стоимость книг более 5000 руб и результат отсортировать по убыванию стоимости.

```
    SELECT author, SUM(price*amount) AS Стоимость
FROM book
WHERE title <> 'Идиот' AND title <> 'Белая гвардия'
GROUP BY author,price
HAVING SUM(price*amount)>5000
ORDER BY price DESC;
```

Отобраны неверные записи

Query result:

| author | Стоимость |
| --- | --- |
| Есенин С.А. | 9750.00 |

Affected rows: 1

Comment: Структуру таблицы нам угадывать?

Comment: `price` из группировки уберите

Comment: ORDER BY Стоимость DESC;

Answer (score 0):

author, SUM(price*amount) - дает по всем книгам одного автора, а не в разрезе автор и книга

GROUP BY author,price  - группирует по автору и цене тоесть вы получите сумму по конкретной цене (если она была одна на все книги одного автора то один результат, если цена разная, то столько раз будет складывать

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=89dfbd23b43ae25394f5a86e3e5eefca

вот пример реализации.

```
SELECT author, SUM(price*amount) AS Стоимость
FROM book
WHERE title not in('Идиот','Белая гвардия')
GROUP BY author
HAVING SUM(price*amount)>5000
ORDER BY SUM(price*amount) DESC;
```

PS в ордере можно обращаться к присвоеному имени поля если поместить запрос в подзапрос:

```
SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT author, SUM(price*amount) AS Стоимость
       FROM book
       WHERE title not in('Идиот','Белая гвардия')
       GROUP BY author
       HAVING SUM(price*amount)>5000) AS T
ORDER BY Стоимость DESC;
```